# How to initialize Model attributes only at time of save?

Tags: backbone.js, appcelerator, appcelerator-alloy

I want my model to have a unique generated id in specific format.

I tried to do this in Backbone.Model.initialize method. 
https://gist.github.com/nirmaljpatel/7bbc891966f0bd1dbee5

However, initialize gets called on Collection.fetch as well.

How do I allocate unique Ids on first time initialization only?

Comment: Why would you initialize the same model twice? You could just either fetch the model, **or** the collection.

Comment: initialize gets called by fetch only for new models that came with the fetch unless you pass specific options. Can we sample code in question..?

Comment: This is in context of Appcelerator where model & collections are saved to SQLite (instead of REST server). The code should be visible on the linked gist. The model gets initialised correctly when I do a first model.save(); However, on a later Collection.fetch() to read back from SQLite, the initialize method fires again.

Answer (score 0):

In your `initialize()` function you use `set()` but sync the change to the SQLite database. So, next time the model is fetched (e.g. via the Collection) it will still be empty and re-set. Instead of `set()` you should use `save()`.